Can I use Topkis theorem with two decision variables? Current Topkis result doesn't match graphical computation of optimal values
I’m using Topkis Theorem to check the effect of a change in a variable in my optimal solution, assuming that if $df/dyt>0$, then $(dy^*)/dt>0$ also holds. For context, $x$ and $y$ are my decision variables and $t$ is a relevant parameter whose effect on both $x$ and $y$ I want to show analytically.
Below my  original function and relevant derivatives:
$$f[x,y]≔s*x+s*(1-x)*(1-a*(1-y))-d*(1-x)*(1-a*(1-y))*b-k*(1-t)*x^2-j*y^2$$
$$df/dy=-abd(1-x)+as(1-x)-2jy$$
However, although for my original function the resulting $df/dyt=0$, which would suggest $(dy^*)/dt=0$ as well should hold, that does not seem the case. I discovered that while graphing optimal $y^*$ for several $t$ values:
optimal y with respect to t
Trying to get the derivative of my optimal $y^*$ with respect to t shows it can be different than $0$:
$$y^*=(\frac{(abd-as)(-bd+abd+2k-as-2kt))}{a^2 b^2 d^2-4jk-2a^2 bds+a^2 s^2+4jkt}$$
$$dy^*/dt=-\frac{2ak(bd-s)(-2bdj+2aj(bd-s)+a^2 (-bd+s)^2 )}{(a^2 (-bd+s)^2+4jk(-1+t))^2} $$
Any advice in how to solve this? Am I wrong using Topkis Theorem when I have two decision variables? Or is it that  I cannot extend the theorem to if $df/dyt=0$, then $dy^*/dt=0$? Any advice would be much appreciated.
